# Kivy parser error when setting color on one machine but not another

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a program running fine on one device (laptop) but when trying to run the same code on another device (workstation), I have an error which does not occur on my laptop.

Setting colors in the .kv file works fine on my laptop but running on my workstation I have this error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\danrf\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-08-19_103.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc3, git-20c14b2, 20200615
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\danrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\danrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 185 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer, img_gif ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 452.06'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 980 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
Connecting to database...
Connected to database!
Parser: File "C:\Users\danrf\Source\Repos\DRFielding\ProDuck\src\GUI.kv", line 109:
...
    107:                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 1}
    108:                font_size: 20
>>  109:                color:"grey"
    110:
    111:<RegistrationWindow>
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'grey'
  File "C:\Users\danrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 705, in _apply_rule
    setattr(widget_set, key, value)
  File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 498, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 527, in kivy.properties.Property.set
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 2009, in kivy.properties.ColorProperty.convert
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 2029, in kivy.properties.ColorProperty.parse_str
  File "C:\Users\danrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 120, in get_color_from_hex
    value = [int(x, 16) / 255.
  File "C:\Users\danrf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 120, in <listcomp>
    value = [int(x, 16) / 255.

Stack trace:
 >  File "C:\Users\danrf\source\repos\DRFielding\ProDuck\src\ProDuck.py", line 692, in build
 >    GUI = Builder.load_file(local_directory + "\\GUI.kv")
 >  File "C:\Users\danrf\source\repos\DRFielding\ProDuck\src\ProDuck.py", line 696, in <module>
 >    ProDuck().run()
Loaded '__main__'
Loaded 'kivy.app'
Loaded 'runpy'
```

I am not sure why this error comes up, both devices have the same install of Kivy, same code etc. and setting colors using the words ("grey") works fine on the first machine.  This error is specific to one line, but removing it throws the same error to another instance of setting the color.
Can anyone shed some light?

Edit: Minimal runable example

```
    def build(self):
        self.icon = local_directory + "\\LogoTransparent.png"
        GUI = Builder.load_file(local_directory + "\\GUI.kv")
        return GUI
```

```
<LoginWindow>:
    name: "Login"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: app.color_build
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    username: username
    password: password
    image: image

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 10,10,10,10
        RelativeLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height
            Label:
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 1}
                text: app.version_number
                font_size: 15
                color:"grey"
            ImageButton
                id: image
                size_hint: 0.72, 0.72
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 0.45}
                source: "LogoTransparent.png"
                allow_stretch: True
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label
                text: "ProDuck"
                font_size: 50
                color:"orange"
            Label
                text: "Data-Driven Productivity"
                color: "grey"
                font_size: 20
            Label
                text: "Username"
                color:"grey"
            TextInput:
                id: username
                size_hint:(0.2, None)
                height: 50
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30
                write_tab: False
                on_text_validate: root.login_press()
            Label
                text: "Password"
                color:"grey"
            TextInput:
                id: password
                size_hint: (0.2, None)
                height: 50
                multiline: False
                password: True
                font_size: 30
                write_tab: False
                on_text_validate: root.login_press()
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                Button
                    size_hint: (0.5,0.5)
                    text: "Reset Password"
                    background_normal: "white"
                    background_color: (1,0.75,0.0,1.0)
                Button
                    size_hint:(0.5,0.5)
                    text: "Login"
                    background_normal: "white"
                    background_color: (1,0.75,0.0,1.0) 
                    on_press: 
                        root.login_press()
                        root.ids.password.text = ""
                        root.ids.username.text = ""
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: 0,10,0,0
                Button:
                    size_hint: (1,0.6)
                    text: "Create profile"
                    background_normal: "white"
                    background_color: (1,0.75,0.0,1.0) 
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "Reg"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
        RelativeLayout:
            ClockWidget:
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 1}
                font_size: 20
                color: "grey"
```

---

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example

Comment: Have done so, hope it is sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
#:import colormap kivy.utils.colormap
```

to your `kv` file, and change:

```
color: "grey"
```

to:

```
color: colormap["grey"]
```

without that change, I also get an error on that line. But my code continues to run (it just ignores that error).